# How to disable the collapsing feature in twitter bootstrap 3?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

In twitter Bootstrap 3 how do i disable the site collapse feature. I basically want my site to be similiar to this one in a way that the navbar features like the logo, search bar, and ext and the whole body of the website to be centered in the middle of the page until the page cannot center it anymore. It then just stays static. My site is wierd because twitter bootstrap 3 makes your site adjust to the mobile device by making it collapse (which is what i do not want).

Here is my html: http://codebin.org/view/d55ad9fe

Here is my css: http://codebin.org/view/571565ca

(i have tried to make a jsfiddle multiplr times and i am still learning.)

Comment: Here is a bootstrap enabled fiddle, add your html to the html panel and css to the css panel and click update. http://jsfiddle.net/1rtqqo1d/ The code provided is difficult to read otherwise. Plus with jsFiddle, you can run the code and test solutions quicker.. will in help getting people to assist. :)

Comment: Your HTML is malformed. There are missing close quotes, spaces in attributes, too many closing DIV's etc.. Look at this Bootply: http://www.bootply.com/pGpVmUjImk -- Bootply includes Bootstrap for you so that you only need the BODY of the doc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to collapse just remove `collapse` class from your code

For example:

If you were using bootstrap navbar means remove `collapse navbar-collapse` and also remove the toggle `button` also, it will avoid collapse options

For center align use `text-center` class

## [DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/oEXiOkzns1)